# Why am I getting zero?

Tags: c++, templates

In this code (ready to compile):

```
      #include "stdafx.h"
        #include <iostream>
        #include <sstream>

        using std::cout;

        template<class T, int first, int second>
        T make()
        {
            T result = T();
            std::stringstream interpreter;
            interpreter << first << '.' << second;
            interpreter >> result;
            return result;
        }

 template<int first, int second, class T = double>
    struct Make
    {
        typedef T value_type;
        static value_type value;

    };

    template<int first, int second, class T>
    T Make<first,second,T>::value = make<T,first,second>();



    template<int first, int second>
    struct Real
    {
        typedef double type;
        static type value;
    };

        template<int first, int second>
    typename Real<first,second>::type typename Real<first,second>::value = typename Make<first,second>::value;  


       int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        //cout << Make<1,2>::value << '\n';//UNCOMMENT THIS AND SEE WHAT I MEAN
        cout << Real<1,2>::value;
        return 0;
    }
```

Please see the comment 4 lines above.

Comment: Why did I get downvote? Is it not ok to ask question about topic you have problems with?

Comment: It would probably help to list actual and expected output, as well as compiler used.

Comment: No, it's because your question is not clear.  If you said '// comment this out to reproduce the problem', it would make sense.  the code as it stands works fine.

Comment: How to make 1.02? Make<1,02> gives 1.2.

Comment: btw OP, downvoting every answer that is not helpful because your question is unclear is kind of a dick thing to do.  I deleted mine after you clarified the q.

Comment: `return 0;` usually returns 0. Problem?

Comment: @Jimmy - the problem is with the output from the revised code

Comment: I didn't downvote, but here are some ways to improve your question (1) your subject line give no information about the problem.  Imagine looking at a list of 100 questions -- what would make me think I could answer this one?  (2) Don't expect people to compile your code -- tell us what it does.  We're going to look at it and try to figure it out without compiling -- as you saw, people can figure stuff out that way pretty quickly -- it helps if you give all of the information you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me with two tweaks, remove the redundant typename decelerations:

```
template<int first, int second>
typename Real<first,second>::type typename Real<first,second>::value = typename Make<first,second>::value;
```

becomes:

```
template<int first, int second>
typename Real<first,second>::type Real<first,second>::value = Make<first,second>::value;
```

(at least in gcc 4.4.4)

The result is 1.2, 1.2 - which is as expected(?)

Comment: @Nim but did you try to compile the code with just Real<1,2>::value?

Comment: When I comment the first line in main() I get 0. If I leave both, I get 1.2 1.2

Comment: @There & Armen.., erm, in my defense, the comment/uncomment line was not very clear, according to your original question answer is correct, however now that you've clarified it, yes, that makes more sense... kinda harsh on the down vote though... never mind...

Comment: @Nim: No one is charging you, no need to defend, I just wanted to ask you what you get when you delete first line. :) So, what do you get?

Comment: Anyways, on gcc this works fine... would imply then as Armen says above, this is an issue with your compiler...

Comment: @Nim so if you have just Real<1,2>::value you get on console 1.2? using gcc?

Answer (score 4):

That isn't ready to compile (you don't use `typename` where you expect a variable name). After fixing those things, I get `1.2` for both:

http://codepad.org/z3UCiOfK

http://codepad.org/66xnnLbd

Edit: It didn't work in VS 2005. This must be a problem in VC++ (at least in 2005). It's probably related to how they do certain template processing later than the standard requires. That's just a guess, though.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but my guess is the codepad link.  Just paste code into the answer -- SO has pretty good code viewing.

Comment: I've edited with more info after I tried it in VS 2005. So you aren't totally crazy.

Comment: @Lou: Yeah, but SO doesn't run the code and show the output like codepad. The output is the import part here.

Answer (score 2):

If you call Real<1,2>::value before you call Make<1,2>::value, it gets initialized first, so it gets Make<1,2>::value's initial non-initialized value, which is 0.

If you call Make<1,2>::value first, it gets initialized properly with the make() function, it gets the value 1.2.  Then, since Real<1,2>::value gets initialized afterwards, it gets that value.